# DNS lookup for microservices

Tags: dns, ip, microservices

Simple question: supposing I have several backend microservices, which are only ever accessed by application software, is it best practice to:

1. point the application software directly to an IP address? or
2. Assign a subdomain to the services?

My assumptions are that (1) avoids DNS lookup latency whereas (2) makes it easier to update the system if the IP ever changes. Is there anything else that affects this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a subdomain or directly accessing with IP address is not a scalable approach.

I would suggest, point your client application software to an API gateway, which would be the single entry point to these microservices and there should be a service discovery mechanism so that the API gateway can reach to these individual Microservices.

please refer to the following sample diagram.

[image]

1. Client application requesting for data from a specific service and it reaches API gateway
2. API gateway requests discovery server for the latest reachable address for that specific service
3. Discovery Service is giving back the latest reachable address
4. API gateway using that address which it got from the Discovery server to reach the specific service for the resource requested by the client.
5. All the microservices should be registered with the Discovery server when it spins up.

Comment: 1. Where can I place Load balancer? Can Gateway connect to LB and LB connects to Service Discovery? 2. Can DNS be used to route the client request to Gateway?